# Grails Auto-format Line wrap

Tags: grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I was trying to using Crtl+shift+F to format a groovy class in springsource suite tool. However, it doesn't split lines that are very long (more than 80 characters) as it does with java files.

I would appreciate if anybody could recommend me a tool for perform wrapping of lines in groovy files and generally grails projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ does a very nice job of formatting Groovy code. The free version of IntelliJ includes Groovy support, but not Grails support (last time I checked)

Answer (score 1):

What version of STS are you using?  We have recently fixed a few issues regarding formatting of Groovy code in the latest release of Groovy-Eclipse (2.1.1).  The update site is here:

http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e3.6/

This should solve your problem, but if it doesn't, then I'd suggest raising a bug on the issue tracker:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE